# Emptying a dynamic array for re-use during fgets() while loop

Tags: c, stack

I have a dynamic array that stores characters every time a "push" function is called, and then performs the remaining operations in main.

To get user's input, I am using fgets() with stdin as my third parameter. The fgets() will continue to run until the user enters in a character 'q'. Therefore, the user can keep entering new lines of characters followed by "Enter" key.

My question is how can I reset the dynamic array every time for a new line of input? In other words, resetting the dynamic array after the "Enter" key is pressed, and re-use that emptied dynamic array?

```
void reset (structStack *s, char *buffer){
   int i = 0;
   while(isEmpty(s)== false)   //Checks to see if the dynamic array is empty
       pop(s);                 //Calls "pop" function to decrement top value

   for(i = 0; i < 300; i++)    //Resetting the buffer array used with fgets()
       buffer[i] = '\0';
}
```

Since I'm also using fgets() to retrieve characters and stored into some static array, wouldn't I also need to reset my static array? (buffer is my static array used with fgets)

UPDATE:

```
void push ( structStack *s, char buffer){   //Called every time user inputs a character
   s->dArr[s->top] = buffer;   //pushing the character from fgets into a dynamic array
   s->top++;    //Increment the top most value in the stack for adding another character into the dynamic array
}

void pop (structStack *s){
if (isEmpty(s) == false)   //Just checks if the stack is empty
    s->top--;
}

char top ( structStack *s ){
if (isEmpty (s) == false){
    return ( s->dArr[s->top - 1] );
    }
else
    return 'n';   //Just a random letter
}
```

Comment: for(i = 0; i < 300; i++)    
       buffer[i] = '\0'; --> memset ( buffer , 0x00, 300 );

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "reset the dynamic array"? The code you have shown already zeros out the buffer (side note: if you are indeed dealing with strings you can get away with zeroing just the first byte of the buffer). What else do you think needs to be done? `fgets` doesn't care what you previously used the buffer for. Or perhaps you mean reset a count to start from the buffer beginning. You haven't shown enough code for us to know what you mean. So it would help greatly if you provided the rest of your code in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `fgets` overwrites the buffer anyway so I don't see what this question is about

Comment: I have two arrays: one static (for fgets()) and another one but dynamic array for storing characters. The static array is only temporary use.

Comment: maybe you should show that code

Comment: What does having two array got to do with the question? Show the code, otherwise you are just dribbling bits of info to us without giving us the full picture.

Comment: I would show you my entire code, but it's long. So I'm trying to slim it. I added the function that adds the character from buffer static array into a dynamic one.

Comment: So, I'm trying to reset (or empty) that dynamic array where I stored my buffer characters from fgets.

Comment: Isn't that what your reset does already by continuously calling `pop`? Though you could have just set the `top` value straight to 0 instead of popping til it's empty.

Comment: My pop function only decrements the top value. It doesn't remove anything from the dynamic array. The "top" value is only used to retrieve the character at that top value position in the dynamic array. So my dynamic array is still holding characters at other positions. I displayed my top and pop functions in the code above.

Comment: Why do you care what it holds in the rest of the buffer? The `top` value tells you the limit of the **valid** data. That's all you need to know. Functionally it shouldn't matter to your program what is in the rest of the buffer beyond `top`. It's all junk as far as you are concerned which is fine as long as the code is correctly written to never accesses anything beyond `top`.

Comment: It does matter what is in the rest of the dynamic array for my program. I'm trying to match characters from the dynamic array stack with new line of input. If I don't empty out my dynamic array, then it will match up with the characters from the rest of the characters in the dynamic array.

Comment: Then your program has a logic error in the matching code. The correct use of `top` as I said is to mark the point of valid data. No code should ever access anything beyond that at any time.

Comment: Wait, will the dynamic array at the top value position just replace its current character with the new character from input? I think I might know what my problem is.

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency and redundancy purposes, just do this

```
buffer[0] = '\0';
```

And you can now consider the rest of the buffer to be garbage :). What's best here is that `fgets()` can handle this situation gracefully by just appending a `'\0'` after whatever it reads.